# Springframework test: Async not started

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I am using the MockMvcResultMathchers to test my async function but it not work properly.
Here is my function :

```
@GetMapping(
      value = "/v1.0/sms-booking/async-handle",
      produces = {"text/plain"})
@Async
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> smsAsyncHandle(@RequestParam("moLogID ") Integer moLogID ) {
CompletableFuture.runAsync(...);
return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
        ResponseEntity.ok("New Message Received with moLogID " + moLogID + " !"));
}
```

and the test function

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureObservability
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@EnableAsync
class SmsAsyncControllerTest {
@Test
void smsAsyncHandle_returnMoLogID_whenValidParam() throws Exception {
    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(get(SMS_ASYNC_HANDLE_PATH)
            .param("moLogID","1")
            .andDo(print()).andExpect(request().asyncStarted())
            .andReturn();

    mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(mvcResult))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(request().asyncResult(instanceOf(ResponseEntity.class)))
            .andExpect(content().string(containsString("1")));
}
}
```

and when I run test, this is the result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcQph.png)

I want my test function run successfully. I have tried many different ways I found on internet but nothing works. Pls help me to overcome this.

Thanks